# Avoiding full table scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which obtains transactions from the transactions table and transaction detail. Both tables have a big amount of entries, so this query takes a while to return results.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN transac_detail tidts ON (tidts.id_transac = t.id);
```

However, I'm more worried because of the fact that Oracle does a full table scan on both tables, according to explain plan, even though t.id and tidts.id_transac have indexes.

Is there any way to optimize this without touching table structure?

Comment: What does Oracle do? A hash join? Hash joins are really fast, often faster than execution plans that use an index. Show us your explain plan and check whether the statistics are accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's true that the SQL neccessarily would be best served with full table scans. This would really be most obviously true where there is a foreign key between the two, but even then there could be exceptions.

I think the key question is this: "what proportion of the rows from each table are expected to be included in the result set?". If the answer is "100% from each" then you have a clear case for full table scans (and a hash join).

However consider the case where tables A and B are joined, with table A containing 5 rows with a foreign key to table B (the parent) containing a million rows. Obviously here you'd look for a full scan of A with a nested loop join to B (the join column on table B would be indexed because it would have to be a primary or unique key).

In the OP's case though it looks like you'd expect 100% rows to be returned from each table. I'd expect to see a full scan of both tables, and a hash join with TRANSACTIONS(probably the smaller table) being accessed first and built into the hash table. This would be the optimum join method, and I'd just be looking out for a situation where TRANSACTIONS is too big for a single-pass hash join. If the join spills to disk then that could be a performance worry and you'd have to look at increasing the memory allocation or equi-partitioning the two tables to reduce the memory requirement.

Comment: Very thorough answer, as always. +1

Answer (score 2):

Since the query as given just returns everything anyway, full table scan may be actually the fastest way of arriving at the final result. Since I/O is so expensive compared to CPU time, it may be more efficient to just pull everything into memory and making the final join there, than to make an index seek in a loop over one table.

To determine whether the query could actually run any faster, you can try the following approaches:

- look at query plan on only a subset of the data (for example, a range of id's)
- try the query on subsets of varying sizes, see what kind of curve you're plotting here

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a WHERE clause, therefore Oracle is thinking that since it has to return all records from both tables a full table scan will be most efficient.

If you would add a WHERE clause that uses the index, I think you will find that EXPLAIN PLAN will no longer use a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Full table scans are not necessarily bad - it appears that you're not limiting the result set in any way and this might be the most efficient way to execute the query.  You can always verify this by using an index hint and determining the resulting performance change.